# How do I get a substring in C?

Tags: c, string, substring

For example if:

```
z = "xxxx; yyyy";
```

How can I get the substrings so that

```
x = "xxxx"
```

and

```
y = "yyyy"
```

where "xxxx" and "yyyy" can be any string of any length?

Comment: In my opinion, this isn't really too broad, as per the close vote. But it fits the downvote critrion, "Does not show research effort". A simple search of google for C and substring should turn up a ton of answers.

Comment: Are you asking how to split the string with character `';'` as a separator?

Answer (score 4):

You don't get much of built-in strings in C, let alone substrings. When you need a substring, you build it yourself by copying relevant portions of the string into a properly allocated memory buffer, and then you null-terminate the result.

Here is an example:

```
char *c = "xxxx; yyyy";
char x[5], y[5];
memcpy(x, &c[0], 4);
x[4] = '\0';
memcpy(y, &c[6], 4);
y[4] = '\0';
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qsz8V0)

Comment: 'You don't get much of built-in strings in C, let alone substrings' - I wish you woudn't say that.  It's absolutely correct, but it's just so, so depressing when it's spelt out:((.

Comment: @MartinJames My favorite saying is that "C combines the power and performance of assembly language with the flexibility and ease-of-use of assembly language." Of course, it is a joke, but there is a grain of joke [sic] in every joke.